# Import weighted edgelist using igraph

Tags: python, r, igraph, edge-list

I have the following txt file representing a network in edgelist format.

The first two columns represent the usual: which node is connected to which other nodes

The third column represents weights, representing the number of times each node has contacted the other.

I have searched the `igraph` documentation but there's no mention of how to include an argument for weight when importing standard file formats like txt.

The file can be accessed from [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/OClinks_w.txt) and this is the code I've been using:

```
read.graph("Irvine/OClinks_w.txt", format="edgelist")
```

This code treats the third column as something other than weight.

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 14):

does the following cause too much annoyance?

```
g <- read.table("Irvine/OClinks_w.txt")
g <- graph.data.frame(g)
```

if it does then directly from the file you can use

```
g<-read.graph("Irvine/OClinks_w.txt",format="ncol")
E(g)$weight
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python and igraph, the following line of code works to import weights and vertex names:

```
g1w=Graph.Read_Ncol("g1_ncol_format_weighted.txt",names=True)
```

Note: you must tell igraph to read names attribute with `names=True`, otherwise just vertex numbers will be imported.

Where g1_ncol_format_weighted.txt looks something like:

```
A B 2
B C 3
```

To make sure the import worked properly, use the following lines:

```
print(g1w.get_edgelist())
print(g1w.es["weight"])
print(g1w.vs["name"])
```

Comment: This is Python and the poster was using R.

Comment: Very helpful, since I wanted python.  Thanks